# Why the record is not getting in search, If the requested record coloumns don't having 1 or 2 values of 3

Tags: soql, custom-button, pageblocktable, search, inputtext

I am trying to search records based on the 3  input strings.

But the record is not getting If the requested record columns don't have this any one of the values(Aadhar_ID__c, name, First_Name__c).

**Please see the below image:**

See in the below table, Let's assume, the database having 2 records. The 1st record having data with all the columns, the 2nd record doesn't have data in all columns i.e: don't have Adharcard value.

If I search 1st  record with **'paul'** using input string lastname (string we can in below code), The record is displaying. 
 But if I search 2nd record with **'john'**  using  input string lastname. The record is not displaying. Because 2nd record doesn't have adharcard value which we are querying in the search.

[image]

How to get the record even record columns don't have 1 or 2 values of 3. If we search with existing data.

**code:**

```
[SELECT Aadhar_ID__c,name,First_Name__c  
FROM object__c 
WHERE Aadhar_ID__c LIKE :'%'+adharcard+'%' 
   AND name LIKE :'%'+lastname+'%' 
   AND First_Name__c LIKE :'%'+surname+'%'];
```

Comment: I think simply appending this condition to your query should solve your problem: `OR (Aadhar_ID__c = '' AND name = '' AND First_Name__c =''`)

Comment: @RohitMourya - You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Samir Initially, I wasn't sure. Posted it

Comment: @ravindar-admin Please make your question clearer so that community can understand better and you will get solution asap. Have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi@Reshma  & @RohitMourya, I have made changes. Please check, Thank you.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin Edited the answer

Comment: @Rohit Mourya, Not  getting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append this condition to your query:`OR (Aadhar_ID__c = '' AND name = '' AND First_Name__c ='')`

So this is how your final query should be:

```
[select Name,Aadhar_ID__c,First_Name__c from Account Where (Aadhar_ID__c Like :'%'+adharcard+'%' OR Name Like :'%'+lastname+'%' OR First_Name__c Like :'%'+surname+'%' )];
```

Comment: Hi@Rohit, Getting 4 errors: unexpected syntax: 'mismatched input ')' expecting SEMICOLON' , unexpected syntax: 'mismatched input 'AND' expecting RPAREN', , unexpected syntax: 'mismatched input 'AND' expecting SEMICOLON', unexpected syntax: 'mismatched input 'OR' expecting RSQUARE'

Comment: @RavindarAdmin It should be fine now

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I think you didn't get my query. If i search with 1 input or more than 1 input, I am getting record. That's fine. But it is looking for the record which must having 3 field values. If not, it is not fetching the record.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin - Please update your question with an example.

Comment: @Samir, I shared sf record with image, also when the record is displaying and when not displaying.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin I've updated the answer. Give it a try. Also Eric answer seems to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OR not AND

```
    [SELECT Aadhar_ID__c,name,First_Name__c  
FROM object__c 
WHERE Aadhar_ID__c LIKE :'%'+adharcard+'%' 
   OR name LIKE :'%'+lastname+'%' 
   OR First_Name__c LIKE :'%'+surname+'%'];
```

Using AND means all three must match. Using OR means only 1 needs to match

Comment: @ Eric, Thanks for the reply. But it is displaying all the records.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin - It is not possible for that query to display "all the record' unless all the records match at least one of the criteria which it your stated goal. Return records where any one of the filters are true

Comment: Hi@ Eric, Please check the question,  I made changes. Thank you.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin your updates don't change my answer. If you want records where at least one value matches then this answer is correct imho. Maybe show an example of s record it gets that it should not and the values you are filtering on